# How to Convert Multiple Text Files Into Multiple json Files

Tags: python, json, pandas, text, file-conversion

I have multiple text files which I need to convert to json files. For each text file I want an individual json file.

#### Text file content

`File-1.txt`

```
['education~25,850,103,23', 'experience~28,94,107,27', 'skills~29,904,59,27']
```

`File-2.txt`

```
['introduction~211,143,87,13', 'education~169,302,131,17', 'skills~322,421,84,15', 'experience~325,142,112,14', 'reference~320,699,68,14']
```

and so on ...

The expected output is a json file which contains:

- Keyword(Class name)
- Values(Coordinates)

This is what I tried with this code I was able to write data into txt--

```
with open(PATH_TO_RESULTS + '/' + os.path.join(os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(image_path)))  + '.txt', 'w') as f:
        image_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(image_path))[0]
#        f.write((image_path + '|'))
        req_fields = []
        for key, value in field_item.items():
            #print("=====================")
            # print(key)
            # print((scores[0, index]))
            # print(value)
            # print("==================")
            merge = str(key.decode('utf-8')) + '~' + str(value)
            req_fields.append(merge)
        f.write(str(req_fields))
        print("#######################Required Fields###########################",req_fields)
```

And one more thing, the json file name should also be the same as txt file name.

Comment: and how is your code?

Comment: First, format your questions, compare yours to the edited version and you will see that is way easier to read. Second, SO is not a place to get others program your code for free. Post your code and we will help with the errors or the difficulties you find. And third, how can xmin be 565 and xmax 228? I think you need to explain a bit more what you need.

Comment: @GiovaniSalazar Kindly check I updated the question...

Comment: @Adirio Kindly check I updated the question...

Comment: The question is way better now, but I would keep the expected output too as that may help users to understand exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that it's what you need. Or at least so close.
You can improve and adapt it(Best naming)

```
import glob, os
import json

os.chdir(".")

def read_file(file):
    with open(file, 'r') as file:
        return file.read()


def write_json(file, data):
    with open(file, 'w') as fout:
        json.dump(data, fout, indent=4)

for file in glob.glob("*.txt"):
    content = read_file(file)

    to_parse_in_rows = content.replace('[', '').replace(']', '').split(', ')

    rows = []

    for part in to_parse_in_rows:
        field12, field3, field4, field5 =  part.replace("'", '').split(',')

        field1, field2 = field12.split('~')

        row = {
            'class': field1,
            'field2': int(field2),
            'field3': int(field3),
            'field4': int(field4),
            'field5': int(field5)
        }

        rows.append(row)

    write_json(file.replace('.txt', '.json'), rows)
```

Comment: Perez What about the above text file is the list in that case how can i access that list and do manipulation to get above code output....